# finding the unique maximizer of the function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, optimization

I need to maximize the following expression with respect to $x$. We know that $x \in [0,a]$ and $b < \frac{a}{36}.$

$$ \max_{x \in [0,a]} x ( 27(a-x)^2 - 22(a-x)^2 \sqrt{ 1 +  \frac{7ab}{(a-x)^2} } + 70ab ) $$

In my numerical analysis, I always obtain unique maximizer $p$. My question is that is there any way/approach to show that $p$ is unique? Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried standard calculus techniques such as setting $f'(x) =0$, looking at the sign of $f''(x)$ and then checking the endpoints of the interval $[0,a]$ and comparing the values? This will allow you to determine the global maxima on $[0,a]$.

Comment: @Dayton, yes. The problem is that $f'(x)$ is not in the good form to pin down $x$.

Answer (score 1):

*Too long for a comment.*

I do not think that we could obtain any formal solution. However, we can simplify the problem.

Assuming $a>0$ and $b>0$, let $x=a y$ and $b=ka$. So, we need to maximize
$$f(y)=y \left(27 (1-y)^2-22 (1-y)^2 \sqrt{1+\frac{7 k}{(1-y)^2}}+70 k\right)$$ for $0\leq y \leq 1$ and $0\leq k\leq \frac 1{36}$.

Using numerical optimization, what I found is that the maximum is always very close to $\frac {20}{27}$ obtained for $y=\frac 13$ (this is the solution for $k=0$); however, this is the global maximum for $k \lt k_*$ where $f(y)=70k_*$. As soon as $k>k_*$, the maximum value is obtained at $y=1$. Numerically $k_* \sim 0.01397807 \sim \frac 1{72}$.